# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect' in the pgdb module using python

Tags: python, postgresql, pgdb

```
    import pgdb
    myConnection = pgdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=database )
    doQuery( myConnection )
    myConnection.close()
```

I get the following error when i run the script.

```
>>> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'. Please help me out
```

Comment: After the import statement, do `dir(pgdb)` and post the output.

Comment: You have new mail in /var/mail/ubuntu. This is what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classname is `Connection` in the repo https://github.com/KehaoWu/pgdb/blob/master/pgdb/pgdb.py#L15

PYPY project pypi.org/project/pgdb

Answer (score 0):

It is like that you have installed the "wrong" pgdb module. Try this:

```
python3.9 -m pip uninstall pgdb
python3.9 -m pip   install PyGreSQL
```

"You may either choose to use the “classic” PyGreSQL interface provided by the pg module or else the newer DB-API 2.0 compliant interface provided by the pgdb module." per http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pgdb/introduction.html . It is confusing to have two different modules with the same name.